# Invoke-RestMethod not passing System.Object[] field in the payload correctly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

The json payload look like this:

```
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "scope": "scope1",
      "claim": "scope1",
      "id": ["123", "567"]
    },
    {
      "scope": "scope2",
      "claim": "claim2",
      "id": ["321", "765"]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
> $inputjson = (((get-content .\inputfile.json) -Join " " ) | convertfrom-json )

> echo $inputjson

 clients                                                                               
 -------                                                                 
 {@{scope=scope1; claim=scope1; id=System.Object[]}, @{scope=scope2; claim=claim2; id=System.Object[]}}
```

Able to see the **id** values by accessing `$inputjson.clients[0].id`, but with this payload of `id=System.Object[]` in `$inputjson`, the API is not recognizing it. I'm using `Invoke-RestMethod` to POST the payload to API.

Any idea how to parse the `id=System.Object[]` in the payload, so that API recognize it correctly?

Btw, the same input json (as-is) is recognized by API with a cURL cmd.

Comment: How is your api expecting the arguments?

Comment: @Daniel: API is expecting the Clients as a model and model is defined according to the input json as described above. As I said, the same json works with the cURL cmd.


```[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]Clients client) { }```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of converting JSON to .NET objects using the [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet and posting the .NET objects, you can post plain JSON like this:

```
$myJson = @"
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "scope": "scope1",
      "claim": "scope1",
      "id": ["123", "567"]
    },
    {
      "scope": "scope2",
      "claim": "claim2",
      "id": ["321", "765"]
    }
  ]
}
"@
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "" -Method Post -Body $myJson -ContentType "application/json"
```

If you want to process your JSON, that you read from your file, before posting it, you can convert it like you did and convert it back to plain JSON. Depending on your PowerShell version, you might need to use the `-Depth` parameter, when converting from or to JSON.

Comment: Nice alternative. It does work for my situation. Thank you!

Comment: @Zeigeist this is not an "alternative", this is the proper way to do it. You always POST json as plaintext when using Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod

Comment: @bluuf: This is indeed an alternative solution, as answer suggests that sending a plain json as a payload. Pls see stackprotector answer above.